# zendframework 2 form populating checkbox values from a database

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using zendframework 2 and doctrine 2. I want to populate the values of my checkboxes from values in my database (dependence injection).

I got the technique from: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md

This is my element (it works for select elements but not for checkboxes):

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox',
    'name' => 'timesId',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Please Select Your Availablity',
        'value_options' => array(
            'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
            'target_class'   => 'FormDependencies\Entity\AvailablityTimeTableList',
             'property'       => 'job',
         ),
     ),
     'attributes' => array(
         'value' => '1' //set checked to '1'
     )
 ));

public function getObjectManager()
{
    return $this->objectManager;
}
```

I cannot find the native doctrine 2 method for checkboxes.

The error message:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager as array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved it;

under type i needed to specify that its a :

```
'type'    => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
```

**the complete code:**

```
$this->add(array(
        'type'    => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
        'name'    => 'timesId',
        'options' => array(
            'label'          => 'Please Select Your Availablity',
            'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
            'target_class'   => 'FormDependencies\Entity\AvailablityTimeTableList',
            'property'       => 'times',
            'empty_option'   => '--- please choose ---'
        ),
```